# Why is it that a coupled mass-spring system will always produce a diagonalizable matrix?

Tags: spring, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, coupled-oscillators, linear-systems

If you take a system like the one in the image, and you do the $y=x'$ trick to turn it into a first-order system of equations ($x_{1}$ or $x_{2}$ being the displacement of the mass $m_{1}$ or $m_{2}$ respectively from equilibrium), you'll get a $4 \times 4$ matrix that could have repeated eigenvalues but will always have 4 eigenvectors according to a professor of mine. However, I would like to see a proof.

[image]

Comment: A proof, in physics??   The text of your question is leading towards MathSE , based on the formal treatment and  properties of matrices, as referred to here : http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys3210/phys3210_sp14/lecnotes.2014-03-31.Intro_to_Coupled_Oscillators.html

Comment: This system has two degrees of freedom hence two normal modes. A standard procedure will lead to second order equations of motions in terms two by two matrices. These matrices are real and symmetric hence they can be orthogonaly diagonalized. I suppose that when transforming it to a system of first order equations the four by four matrices are still symmetric.

Comment: May be helpful my answers *herein (1)* :  [**Eigenvalue equation for kinetic and potential energy**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266889/eigenvalue-equation-for-kinetic-and-potential-energy/267096#267096) and *therein (2)* : [**Can we let the lowest of n by equal (lenght and k) springs connected masses in equilibrium move in a siusoid way after giving the lowest a pull?**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/334217/can-we-let-the-lowest-of-n-by-equal-lenght-and-k-springs-connected-masses-in-e/334872#334872).

Comment: @Countto10 : It would be reasonable imo to ask though "what is the _physical_ intuition/reasoning behind the eigenvectors and why then _physically_ there should be 4?".

Comment: @mike4ty4 You are correct, and I was too flippant. I have upvoted the question and I  take your point to emphasise that a physics viewpoint  is often (always?) available and preferable. Thanks